# add custom files in extjs6 application build

Tags: extjs6

With ExtJs 5, I used to add custom files int the `"resources"` section of `app.json`

```
"resources": [
    'index.php',
    'util.inc.php',
    'get-file.php',
    'form-upload-file.php',
    'wsdl/',
    'controllers/'
],
```

But in extjs6, if I put pathes into `"resources"` section of `app.json`, there're put into the `resources` folder (and a folder's files are put right into `resources`, not into `resources/folder_name`

I've tried to hack into `"build"` section to add another destination directory, but I did not succeed, nor I found any documentation.

Is there a way to achieve previous behaviour ? (other than write a script to be ran after `sencha app build` ?)

Comment: ressource and resource are the same folders?

Comment: Yes, I'm french and often make this spelling error ;)

Comment: ok ty no problem just difficult to read

Comment: so your problem is that folders like wsdl and controllers are not in resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,you can put your folders in the resources folder manually and then use something like this to copy them on build

```
    "resources": [
      "resources/fonts/",
      "resources/images/",
      "resources/json/"
   ],
```

personally, i put the files that aren't in a folder (like your php files) in a folder them selves. (like my json folder, that contains about 15 jsons) So you can import them only requiring a folder.

Other possibilities [in this discussion](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279121-Can-I-have-a-folder-automatically-copied-to-the-Build-folder/page2)

Comment: If I do that, I need to rewrite URLs all over the application, and I prefer not to if possible

Comment: so your folders need to be whit index.html?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, yes

Comment: have you got a build-impl.xml?

Comment: `sencha app build` generated .sencha/app/build-impl.xml

Comment: have a look to this discussion https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279121-Can-I-have-a-folder-automatically-copied-to-the-Build-folder/page2